# Make a BattleShip Board from a txt

Tags: c++

I need some really huge help sorting this thing out

Here's my `Board` and `Player` classes:

```
class Board {
public:
    Board(const string &filename);
    //bool putShip(const Ship &s);
    void moveShips();
    //bool attack(const Bomb &b);
    void display()const;
    void show()const;
    void initializeGrid();

private:
    int numLines, numColumns;
    //vector <Ship> ships;
    vector <vector<int> > board;
};

class Player{
public:
    Player(string playerName, string boardFileName);
    void showBoard() const;
    //Bomb getBomb() const;
    //void attackBoard(const Bomb &b);
private:
   string name;
   Board board;
};
```

This is not made by me, these are the classes I need to implement on my final c++ project.

I'm struggling with making the board (developing the function `void Player::viewBoard()`)

The txt file will be something like this

```
Board 10x10
```

and I already developed a function that reads both 10's and saves it in `numLines` and `numColumns`:

```
Board::Board(const string &filename){
    string tmp;
    ifstream config;
    config.open(filename.c_str()); 

    if (config.is_open()) {
        config >> tmp >> numLines >> tmp >> numColumns;
    }
}
```

But now what? How can I make a Board for the Player player with the dimensions specified on the board?

Any help?  I really appreciate any help guys, this can save my semester. Thank you all and best regards.

Comment: This for your "final c++ project" and this is as far as you've got? :-\
Next semester try attending the class and doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

well the class definition says that the board is a vector of vectors of ints

You need to make numlines vectors of numcolumns ints and store them in board. (read up on std::vector)

I assume each int represents the contents of that cell. YOu have to decide what each value means - or did the class designer already decide that. Since we cant see the other methods we dont know

Answer (score 0):

"Making a Board for the Player" essentially means that you create an instance of the Board class which is a private member of the Player class. You already have the object declared in the Player class, so you just need to instantiate it. You can create a pointer to that class and then de-reference that pointer. For example:

```
Foo *f = new Foo(/*params*/);
foo = *f;
```

assuming that "foo" has already been declared as a private member.

Comment: Board *f = new Board("configp1.txt");
 board = *f;

Like this?

Comment: I don't want to give you the answer, you should try it and test your program.

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize you 'board' variable with the dimension you got from the file using 'resize' (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) method.